# How to create a form search in dynamic ways Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a form like this :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal'
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'tanggal_cek')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'form-control'
    ]
]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'lokasi')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'created_by')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => $mapDataUser,
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Choose .. '
    ]
]) ?>
```

Now, I have to manipulate the result that came from this form to find data in my database.
SO far I've created like this :

```
if ($model->load($request->post())) {
  $tanggalCek = $model->tanggal_cek ? Yii::$app->formatter->asDate($model->tanggal_cek, "php:Y-m-d") : "";
  $lokasi = $model->lokasi;
  $created_by = $model->created_by;

  $model = StockTakingTli::find()
           ->where(['tanggal_cek' => $tanggalCek])
           ->andWhere(['LIKE', 'lokasi', $lokasi])
           ->andWhere(['created_by' => $created_by])
           ->all();
```

You know, the AR working in sequence.
My question is, is it possible AR to find dynamically ?
Because, sometimes `tanggal_cek` is null, and `lokasi` is set, vice versa, and on...and on..

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filterWhere()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#filterWhere()-detail), it automatically ignores empty values:

```
$query->filterWhere([
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build dinamic query filter using   `filterWhere()` and `andFilterWhere()`   functions  instead of `where()` and `andWhere()`  ...
The filterWhere  functions ignore condition with empty values

```
 $model = StockTakingTli::find()
           ->filterWhere(['tanggal_cek' => $tanggalCek])
           ->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'lokasi', $lokasi])
           ->andFilterWhere(['created_by' => $created_by])
           ->all();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#filterWhere()-detail
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querytrait.html#andFilterWhere()-detail